# Is it possible to enable hot reload on iOS and Android simulators simultaneously?

Tags: android, ios, intellij-idea, dart, flutter

I've set up flutter with IntelliJ and got to the point where demo app is running on both simulators, however hot reload seems to be only updating one of them, is it possible to update both at the same time? Here is example of the issue in action

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose this happens only when run from IDE. Try starting both simulators and run app from command line interface.

To run app from terminal on all simulators:
`flutter run -d all`

For hot reload press `r` key on keyboard

Comment: Is there a repo for intelliJ plugin where I could report this? Tried to google for it, nothing related comes up

Comment: @Ilja Yes, of course. [Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij) is the github link where you can raise a issue regarding.

Comment: How much RAM does it take to start them simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

For visual studio code users ; you can create 2 launch task. 
Launch the first one on a device, and the second on the other one.

Debug will work simultaneously on both. Even breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

As an update, flutter.io best describes how to switch between iOS and Android simulators wrt your favorite IDE at:
[setup your favorite IDE & test drive flutter](https://flutter.io/get-started/test-drive/#androidstudio).

From then on hot reload works for simulators simultaneously.